# Matlab substitution within matrices not working as intended

Tags: matlab, substitution

Where does the following matlab code go wrong?

```
C=sym('a',[2,1]);
A=sym('aa',2);

A(1,1)=C(1)-10*C(2)*C(2);
A(2,2)=C(2);

subs(A(1,1),C(1),solve(trace(A)==1,C(1)));

disp(A);
```

As I understand it, the diagonal elements of A are set to functions of a1 and a2. Then, in the expression at position A(1,1), substitute for C(1) (which is a1), the solution to trace(A)==1 for the variable C(1). But when you display the matrix A, it seems unchanged.

What is the error? Why is subs not working as intended? The above is the smallest non-working example of large code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no error in the code. The `subs = subs(s, old, new)` function returns by definition a copy of `s` after all occurrences of `old` are replaced with `new`, and then evaluates `s`.

What your code does is: Define `A`, call `subs` and then display `A`. Since `subs` does not effect the entries of `A` by the above explanation, you get the "old" `A` displayed.

Hence, if you want to replace the value `A(1, 1)` with the expression which `subs` created for you, you should e.g. use

```
A(1, 1) = subs(C(1) , solve(trace(A) == 1, C(1)));
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you try to replace the element at A(1,1) with the result from solving the equation. In this case, you should do something like that:

```
C = sym('a',[2,1]);
A = sym('aa',2);
A(1,1) = C(1);
A(2,2) = C(2);
A(1,1) = subs(C(1),solve(trace(A) == 1, C(1)));
disp(A);
```

This will display the following:

```
[ 1 - a2, aa1_2]
[  aa2_1,    a2]
```

Comment: Thanks, but i have to use subs. Elements of A might be complicated functions in variables of C, and i want to be able to *substitute* them after solving equations. I'll edit the question to accommodate what i am asking.